# Disable header overwriting of Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, header, overwrite, disabled-input

Is there a way to tell Zend that it shouldn't overwrite my set headers. I am using a external library which sets an own header, and Zend is always overwriting it.

Comment: What type of "header"? Http header? Email headers? HTML header on your view?

Comment: Http headers like 'WWW-Authenticate' and Status.

Comment: Could you use the third party library to add them onto Zend's    $response->setHeaders($response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine( 'headername', 'headerval' ) ); ?"